# Angular Observable Issue on server

Tags: angular, http, angular2-observables

I've created a service in Angular 6 which runs fine on ngOnInit via subscribe but once I try to get the response via a function / click event i receive the following error.

ERROR DOMException: Failed to set the 'responseType' property on 'XMLHttpRequest': The response type cannot be changed for synchronous requests made from a document.

I suspect i'm doing something silly - the data returns fine in a fetch .then call so i'm ruling out server config and so far still working through Angular theory so posting in here just in case it is something glaringly obvious to someone with more experience.

localhost it works fine but when i build / move the code to the server the error is appearing - any ideas?

Kind regards
Rachel

Service

```
export class GetVehicleResultsService {
  url = 'SOME_URL';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getVehicles() {
    return this
      .http
      .get<Vehicle>(`${this.url}`, {
        responseType: 'json',
        params: {
          keyword: '*'
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Component

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this
      .getVehicleResultsService
      .getVehicles()
      .subscribe(
        vehicles => {
          this.vehicles = vehicles.response.docs;
          this.facets = vehicles.facet_counts.vcj_facet_fields;
      });
  }
// this call works and consoles the data 
  test() {

    fetch('SOME_URL')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json));
  }
// this doesn't work

test() {
this
          .getVehicleResultsService
          .getVehicles()
          .subscribe(
            vehicles => {
              this.vehicles = vehicles.response.docs;
              this.facets = vehicles.facet_counts.vcj_facet_fields;
          });

      }
```

Comment: If you're using `HttpClient` you don't need `response.json()`, but that would likely give you a different error. Which line is giving you that error?

Comment: the response.json() is returning data - the service call from the test function is giving the error - sorry my comments should have been clearer

Comment: How do you call the test() method from your html template?

Comment: Just a (click)=“test()” from a button element